# How can I keep my module's Python logger from outputting to the console?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I've given my logger an output file using a FileHandler, like this:

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger('my_module')

handler = logging.FileHandler(filename = str(self.log_file), mode = "a")
datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt = "[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d][%(name)s:%(levelname)s]: %(message)s", datefmt = datefmt)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

self.logger.addHandler(handler)
```

This code is used, it logs to both the console and the output file.

If I add this code:

```
default_logger = logging.getLogger()
default_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

It stops the logging to both the console and the output file.

I can't figure out how to make the logger only log to the `filename` I pass to its handler. How can I do this?

---

Here's what I've tried:

```
# LOGS TO CONSOLE AND FILE

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

self.logger = logging.getLogger('my_module')
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename = str(self.log_file), mode = "a")
datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt = "[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d][%(name)s:%(levelname)s]: %(message)s", datefmt = datefmt)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

self.logger.addHandler(handler)
self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)



# LOGS TO NEITHER CONSOLE OR FILE

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

self.logger = logging.getLogger('my_module')
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename = str(self.log_file), mode = "a")
datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt = "[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d][%(name)s:%(levelname)s]: %(message)s", datefmt = datefmt)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

self.logger.addHandler(handler)
# self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)



# LOGS TO CONSOLE AND FILE

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

self.logger = logging.getLogger('my_module')
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename = str(self.log_file), mode = "a")
datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt = "[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d][%(name)s:%(levelname)s]: %(message)s", datefmt = datefmt)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
# handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

self.logger.addHandler(handler)
self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)



# LOGS TO CONSOLE AND FILE

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
# root_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

self.logger = logging.getLogger('my_module')
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename = str(self.log_file), mode = "a")
datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt = "[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d][%(name)s:%(levelname)s]: %(message)s", datefmt = datefmt)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
# handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

self.logger.addHandler(handler)
self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: You should be able to fix it by setting the level for your logger and handler.

Comment: I set my handler's level to `logging.INFO` and the logger's level to `logging.WARNING`. That stops the INFO logging to console, but it also stops the INFO logging to the file handler.

Comment: If the logger's level is warning, info messages not being sent to the file is the expected behavior. Both the logger and handler should be set to info. You should still set the root logger to warning, as you've already done, if you don't want it to send messages to the console.

Comment: You might be misunderstanding me—I want it to send logs to the file but not the console. If I set the root logger to warning it stops it from sending to both of those, which I don't want. Is there a way to send the log to only the file?

Comment: You need to set the level in both loggers, in your code you have only set the root logger's level. You must also set the level for the `my_module` logger.

Comment: I haven't been updating the question based on your recommendations, but I just edited it to add what I've tried. Setting the level for my module's logger and the root logger just logs to both the console and the file.

Comment: Your first example, with levels set for everything, does what it should for me. No console output and messages in the log file. Are you importing another module that is doing something with logging?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I am using another module that uses the Python `logging` module. I get it through `logging.getLogger('deemix')`, set its level to `logging.WARNING`, and then give it the same handler that I give my module's logger. I just tried giving it a different (but functionally the same) instance of the handler, but that didn't help.

Comment: When I remove the code that modifies the `deemix` logger, it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: The code you've posted so far works as expected, you'll need to figure out which code you're adding is causing the problem. It might be worth inspecting the logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict after you've done all your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are doing wrong in your setup, can you try this (something using dictConfig); works for me:

```
import logging
import logging.config

LOG_CONFIG = {'version': 1,
              'handlers': {
                  'file_handler': {'class': 'logging.FileHandler', 'formatter': 'log_formatter', 'filename': '<your_file_name>'},
                  },
              'loggers': {'my_module': {'handlers': ['file_handler'], 'level': 'INFO'}},
              'formatters': {'<your_format>'}}
              }

logging.config.dictConfig(LOG_CONFIG)
self.logger = logging.getLogger('my_module')
```